# Compiling CSS to SWF server side Java, What is the best practice?

Tags: java, css, apache-flex, flash, mxmlc

My project allows users to create custom css for our flex app.

In regards to compiling the CSS into SWFs on the server side:

Should I use the flex2.compiler.css.Compiler class in mxmlc-3.5.0.12683.jar?

Or

Should I invoke mxmlc from Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

The css.Compiler class is not very well documented.  Does anyone have any examples that use this?

For the Runtime exec method, what is the best way to  package mxmlc into the maven build so its available to the server at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is so rare that people try to compile Flex Apps on the fly at the server, that there probably isn't a best practice.  My intuition is that using the jar file makes more sense if your server side code is Java.

But, if documentation is a problem the Flex command line compiler arguments are well documented and may save you a lot of time.